# When evaluating the limit of $f(x, y)$ as $(x, y)$ approaches $(x_0, y_0)$, should we consider only those $(x, y)$ in the domain of $f$?

Tags: calculus, limits

When evaluating the limit of $f(x, y)$ as $(x, y)$ approaches $(x_0, y_0)$, we should or should not consider only those $(x, y)$ in the domain of $f(x, y)$ ? I am confused by different practices of Calculus textbooks. Have anyone searched and found some authoritative opinion ?

Thomas Calculus 14e §14.2 Example 2 (Page 802-803) $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x^2 - x y}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}}$ considers only those $(x, y)$ in the domain. The authors' answer ($\mathbf{0}$) is the same as [the answer by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7B%28x%2C%20y%29%20-%3E%20%280%2C%200%29%7D%20%28x%5E2%20-%20x%20y%29%20%2F%20%28sqrt%28x%29%20-%20sqrt%28y%29%29) . See [textbook page 802](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IJxN.jpg) and [textbook page 803](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KScsf.jpg) .

Larson Calculus 10e §13.2 Exercise 27 (Page 887) $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x - y}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}}$ considers **NOT** only those $(x, y)$ in the domain. The authors' answer (**DNE**) is **NOT** the same as [the answer by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7B%28x%2C%20y%29%20-%3E%20%280%2C%200%29%7D%20%28x%20-%20y%29%20%2F%20%28sqrt%28x%29%20-%20sqrt%28y%29%29) ($\mathbf{0}$). See [textbook page 887](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1rE4.jpg) and [solution manual page 1268](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5qe8.jpg) .

Comment: Hmm... It should be only considering ${(x,y)}$ within the domain of the function

Comment: It is non-sense write the symbol $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: [cross-posted](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18632/13585)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Larson defines the (potential) limit of a function $f$ only at points $P$ where $f$ is defined in a punctured open neighborhood of $P$.

That explains the answer from the answer key.

But it's a minority point of view.

Note that Larson is still only considering points $(x,y)$ approaching $(x_0,y_0)$ where the points $(x,y)$ are in the domain of $f$, but the author is only allowing consideration of limits at points $(x_0,y_0)$ where $f$ is defined in a punctured open neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$.

As evidence for the "minority point of view" claim, the following texts define the (potential) limit of $f$ at a point $P$, assuming only that $P$ is such that every punctured neighborhood of $P$ contains points of the domain of $f$.

- Edwards & Penney -- Calculus - Early Trancendentals, 7th Ed (2007)

  Stewart -- Calculus - Early Transcendentals, 6th Ed (2008)

  Thomas & others -- Calculus, 11th Ed (2004)

Comment: " every punctured neighborhood of P contains points of the domain of f.": such a point is called a *limit point* of the domain.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin: Yes, so the three texts I referenced define the concept of the (potential) limit of a function $f$ at a point $P$, assuming $P$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$. The limit may or may not exist, but the condition on $P$ is a prerequisite for attempting the evaluation.

Comment: I was just giving this concept a name for any readers who may not be familiar with it.